# Concatenate ints to date and inserting to DB in ssis

Tags: sql, date, casting, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and have an issue with a inserting a date to my table with ssis. 
this is what I'm trying to do:

```
select cast (cast(YEAR(getdate()) as nvarchar) + '-' + cast(@IndexmonthS as nvarchar) + '-' + cast(@day as nvarchar) as date)  as startdate,
       cast (cast(YEAR(getdate()) as nvarchar) + '-' + cast(@IndexmonthE as nvarchar) + '-' + cast(@day as nvarchar) as date)  as enddate
```

when I copy it to the commend text in ssis and run the package I get an error -

> "Error at insert to ... cannot convert between types "DT_DBDATE" and
>   "DT_14"..."

the destination table has a the column and its type is date. 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, never use `varchar()` or `nvarchar()` without a length parameter.  In SQL Server, the default length varies by context and is just a bug waiting to happen.

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `datefromparts()`.  Assuming the values are numerical:

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate()), @IndexmonthS, @day) as startdate,
```

Even in earlier versions, you should use `datename()` rather than `datepart()`:

```
select cast(datename(year, getdate()) + '-' + cast(@IndexmonthS as varchar(255)) + '-' cast(@day as varchar(255)) as date)
```